# How to use orderby in IQueryable object?

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

How to use orderby in IQueryable object?

Comment: please be more specific - do you mean how do you call it to create an ordered IQueryable?  Or do you mean how to implement it on your own IQueryProvider?

Answer (score 1):

You use it like so:

```
var orderedResult = yourContext.YourTable
        .OrderBy(yt => yt.SomeValueThatYouWantTheResultOrderedBy);
```

Comment: no i mean i call a function where the Linq to Entities query is written and it returns the IQueryable object.
I want to apply orderby and skip and take extension methods to this object.

Comment: @bbbbb How is that different? In the above example `yourContext.YourTable` is an IQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of klausbyskov's answer, your question should be: *How do I convert an IOrdereQueryable into an IQueryable object?*

In that case, you should convert it to a `List` object first (which means the query will be executed), and then perform a select on the resulting list:

```
var orderedList = (
    from q in MyDataContext.MyTable 
    orderby q.SortColumn 
    select q
    ).ToList();
var queryableList = orderedList.Select(q => q);
```

Note: As I said, the orderedList will be evaluated, so I wouldn't recommend using it for large datasets.